# Automated speech to text layer subtitles in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

Hi I have a video in After Effects that I want to add subtitles as text layers. Previously  I have been typing them out manually. Does anyone know of a way to either automate the subtitling process or any ways to improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer to include Premiere's very effective built-in transcription service:

Your best bet now is probably to finish your video in After Effects, then import it into Premiere, and [transcribe it, then add captions, and export it](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/speech-to-text.html?_branch_match_id=1073900024266301991&utm_source=Adobe-Web&utm_campaign=Branch_vs_Helpx_Test&utm_medium=Web-App&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8soKSkottLXLyhKzc1MLUotKMrXSywo0MvJzMvWz0jy8SoxSY4Kz0gCAGkGj5goAAAA).

If you still want to edit the transcribed text in After Effects, you can [export the subtitles from Premiere as an .SRT file](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/working-with-captions.html#export-captions), and import them into After Effects, as explained below:

**Other methods:**

Assuming it's a video you are happy to make public, you could publish it through youtube and [gather the subtitles from there](https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-ways-to-subtitle-and-caption-your-videos-automatically-using-artificial-intelligence--cms-26834) as an .srt file.

Be aware that automatically generated subs tend to have mistakes in them.

You could manually make subtitles using a free tool like [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/)

Or you could pay a fee to a company like [3playmedia](https://www.3playmedia.com/) to generate the subtitles for you.

Once you have the subs as an .srt file:

Then to apply them in After Effects as burnt-in text, you could use a tool like [PT_importsubtitles](https://aescripts.com/pt_importsubtitles/) to convert the .srt file to timed text layers.